# Is there any reason why a GIF image would show in FF/Chrome and not IE?

Tags: images, browser-support

I've been asked to investigate why the images on a particular site cannot be viewed in IE (6/7 and 8, multiple machines) but is visible in all other browsers.

I've verified that it has nothing to do with the site itself by downloading the image and placing it as an image in a local HTML file, with the same result. Accessing the URL directly in the address bar in IE again does not display the image, only the little red X.

Here's the image in question:

[image: National emergency management agency disaster response map]

*Why would all other browsers show this image except IE?*
*What can I do to get the image to work in IE?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this issue before and the problem was related to the image color mode. If the color mode of the image is CMYK, then IE can not display it properly. The preferred color mode is RGB.

Comment: I'm going to try this and let you know how it works..

Comment: In the past I had this same issue, but IE/Opera showed the image and Firefox did not. Ryan, if you are using Photoshop, make sure you always use the "Save for Web" function because it sorts these problems, and also compresses images very well.